# How to input a mix feature into a LSTM model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Assume, I have two features: x1 and x2. Here, **x1 is a vector of word index** and **x2 is a vector of numerical values**. The length of x1 and x2 are equal to 50. There are 6000 rows for each x1 and x2. I combine these two into one such as

```
X = np.array([np.row_stack((x1[i], x2[i])) for i in range(x1.shape[0])])
```

My initial LSTM model is

```
X_input = Input(shape = (50, 2), name = "X_seq")
X_hidden1 = LSTM(units = 256, dropout = 0.25, return_sequences = True)(X_input)
X_hidden2 = LSTM(units = 256, dropout = 0.25, return_sequences = True)(X_hidden1)
X_hidden3 = LSTM(units = 128, dropout = 0.25)(X_hidden2)
X_dense = Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu')(X_hidden3)
X_dense_dropout = Dropout(0.25)(X_dense)

concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(inputs = [X_dense_dropout])
output = Dense(units = num_category, activation = 'softmax', name = "output")(concat)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = [X_input], outputs = [output])
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics = ["accuracy"])
```

However, I know I need to have an embedding layer to take care of `X[0,:]` right below the Input layer. Thus, I modified my above code to

```
X_input = Input(shape = (50, 2), name = "X_seq")
x1_embedding = Embedding(input_dim = max_pages, output_dim = embedding_dim, input_length = max_length)(X_input[0,:])
X_concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(inputs = [x1_embedding, X_input[1,:]])
X_hidden1 = LSTM(units = 256, dropout = 0.25, return_sequences = True)(X_concat)
X_hidden2 = LSTM(units = 256, dropout = 0.25, return_sequences = True)(X_hidden1)
X_hidden3 = LSTM(units = 128, dropout = 0.25)(X_hidden2)
X_dense = Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu')(X_hidden3)
X_dense_dropout = Dropout(0.25)(X_dense)

concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(inputs = [X_dense_dropout])
output = Dense(units = num_category, activation = 'softmax', name = "output")(concat)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = [X_input], outputs = [output])
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics = ["accuracy"])
```

Python shows an error

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 2, 15), (None, 2)]
```

any suggestion? many thanks

Comment: `x1_embedding` is a 3-dim matrix (Keras automatically adds an additional dimension for the batch size hence the `none` but `X_input[:,1]` is 2-dim i.e. all rows and the index=1 column. You might want to do something like `X_input[:,:,1]` to get the batch dimension too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the input to the `concat` layer has different dimensions and hence we can't `concat` them. To overcome this issue we could just reshape the input to the `concat` layer using `tf.keras.layers.Reshape` like below and the rest will be same.

```
reshaped_input = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1,1))(X_input[:, 1])
X_concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(inputs = [x1_embedding, reshaped_input])
```